# Why this short exact sequence does not split?

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $k$ be a field, and
$$0\longrightarrow k\stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} A \longrightarrow k\longrightarrow 0$$
where $A = k[x]/(x^2)$ and $\alpha$ is given by $\alpha(t) = tx$.

I'd like to show this short exact sequence does not split.

$A$ has a nilpotent element, but $k \oplus k$ does not.

But this requires that one should see them as *rings*.

How could I prove this?

Comment: How would you like to see them, if not as rings?

Comment: @Spenser I mean that if I want to use 'nilpotent', I need to be allowed to multiply elements, but this problem considers $k$ and $A$ as $k$-vector spaces, doesn't it?

Comment: Short exact sequences are usually defined using modules and module homomorphisms. Taking this usual interpretation here, any short exact sequence over a field splits, including this one. Note also that in your  example, $\alpha$ is not a ring homomorphism.

Comment: As vector spaces (modules over $k$) it certainly splits. Probably you have to see this as a short exact sequence of A-modules

Comment: I see now. thank you for both of your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpreting this as a sequence of $A$ modules (as we are all suspecting was intended) one would note that  $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ is directly indecomposable (actually local even.). So no mapping at all like that is going to split it properly.

It can't have a nontrivial pair of summands.  Each half would have to be contained in the unique maximal ideal, and could never generate all of $A_A$.